# Generating a MAC on a Polynomial

Tags: algorithm-design, mac

In the following, all the operations and polynomials are defined over a finite field of prime order, $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a sufficiently large prime number. All polynomials and values below are non-zero.

---

Let $F(x)= R(x)\cdot \phi(x)+Z(x)$, where the degree of each of the polynomials $R,Z$ and $\phi$ is $d>1$. Also, let $Z$ and $R$ be two polynomials picked uniformly at random from the field.  Note $\phi$ is a fixed polynomial.

---

**Question** 1: Is $F(x)$ a MAC of $\phi$(x)?

---

**Question** 2: Is polynomial $\frac{F'(x)-Z(x)}{R(x)}$ a random polynomial distributed uniformly among polynomials of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$? where $F'(x)$ is a fixed polynomial known by the adversary.

Comment: What have you done to try to figure out these questions so far?  What's your definition of a MAC for Q1?  Obviously if $Z$ and $R$ are random variables then some function of them is also a random variable; in Q2 did you mean to ask about a particular distribution, like whether $(F' - Z)/R$ is uniformly distributed among the degree-$d$ polynomials in $\mathbb F_p[x]$?  Can $R$ be zero?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Thanks for useful comments. I have edited the question.